# Memory error in Python. Program takes a lot of RAM memory

Tags: python, memory-management

So this is my code:

```
import re

h_file_name="testinp.txt"     #This file is very large approx 64GB size
m_file_name="testinpmap.txt"  #This files size is between 25-30MB

with open(h_file_name, "rb") as f, open(h_file_name+".re.txt", "wb+") as f1, open(m_file_name,"rb") as f2:


    req=""
    s=""
    cols1 = []

    for line in f:
            cols= re.split('[ ]+|[ ]+', line.strip())
            for i in range(len(cols)):
            if str(cols[i]).strip() == "1":
                    cols[i] = "2"
            cols1.append(cols)


    for line2 in f2:

            cols2 = re.split('[ ]+|[    ]+', line2.strip())

            if (cols2[3].strip() != "."):
                    for j in range(len(cols1[i])):
                            if str(cols1[i][j]).strip() == "0":
                                cols1[i][j] = "1"


    for c in cols1:
            req += " ".join(map(str,c))
            req += "\n"

    f1.write(req)
```

So as you can see the input file is very large, but what I don't understand is that I am reading the file line by line, then why am I getting 
"

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "re_13.py", line 37,
>   in     req += " ".join(map(str,c)) MemoryError"

or why is the program taking too much of RAM memory from the beginning of the code execution ? How can I modify the script so that it takes minimum memory and does not run out of memory?

Comment: You should try `for x in cols1: f1.write(" ".join(map(str, c)) + '\n')`. Appending large strings like `req` is often a bad idea.

Comment: @Yakym Pirozhenko: That did help but I am getting "OOM killer terminated the process", which is probably because of memory allocation in RAM. Any other suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko Also the RAM has 128 GB of memory, very unlikely that OOM error should occur. even if it takes the whole file into memory.